# Asymptotically Solving ODE with free parameters

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I have a first order ODE, $F(y[x], y'[x], A, B) = 0$. I want to solve this numerically (with the boundary value $y[1] = i$ ) but also with the following requirements: A and B are free parameters which can take any value in the range, say (0,1). And for this entire range I'm interested in solutions lying at infinity only and want to have a plot of $(x,y,z)\equiv (A,B,y'[\infty]$). Sorry if I'm being naive, I'm completely new to Mathematica. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the function that I'm using (at the moment I'm also getting some error "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at u==1").

```
M = 1; m = 1; p = 2; q = 1; Q = √3 ; d = 3; L = 1; k = 1; ω = 1;
f[u_] := 1 - M u^(-d)
vneg[u_] := (1/√f[u])[ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))] - Q p u^(2 - d) ;
vpls[u_] := (1/√f[u])[ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))] + Q p u^(2 - d) ;
NDSolve[{y'[u] == (- y[u] 2 m L u + vneg[u] + k + (vpls[u] - k)
         y[u]^2)/ u^2 √f[u], y[1] == I}, y , {u, 1, 40}]
```

Note that `u=1` is a singularity of `f[u]`, but even if I use $1+\epsilon$, with a fairly large $\epsilon$ it's giving me the same error.

For getting $y[\infty]$ I's just trying use large value of `u` (`40` in this example) and test when `y` gets stable. And for the time being I'm setting $k$ and $\omega$ equal to `1` (which are `A` and `B`, essentially).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It does not seem likely that your function can be integrated numerically over an infinite domain.  You need to approximate it by a finite domain.  Then, `ParametricNDSolve` may get you started.  But, to elicit much response from readers, you should provide additional information, such as your function in Mathematica format.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks! The `ParametricNDSolve` allowed me to vary A and B and get a plot of (A,B,y'[finite]) but I'm struggling with that ndnum error.

Comment: I suggest that you update your question with the code that you actually are using now.

Comment: Your code as written contains a syntax error.  `[ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))] ` should be `(ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d)))`.  With this change and a small `ϵ`, the code runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as written contains a syntax error.  Additionally, there is no need to used `SetDelayed`.  Finally, the calculation needs to begin slightly beyond `u == 1`.  With these changes and `NDSolveValue` used for convenience,

```
M = 1; m = 1; p = 2; q = 1; Q = √3 ; d = 3; L = 1; k = 1; ω = 1;
f[u] = 1 - M u^(-d);
vneg[u] = (1/√f[u]) (ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))) - Q p u^(2 - d) ;
vpls[u] = (1/√f[u]) (ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))) + Q p u^(2 - d) ;
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[u] == (- y[u] 2 m L u + vneg[u] + k + (vpls[u] - k)
    y[u]^2)/ u^2 √f[u] , y[1.001] == I}, y , {u, 1.001, 40}];
Plot[ReIm[sol[u]], {u, 1.001, 40}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {u, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :) but it's weird that even if I just copy your code to a new notebook and run it, it does not give me any plot, just a set bare axes! Can it be some precision issue?

Comment: @Skylar15 I just copied the code from StackExchange to a new notebook, and it worked fine.  Precision is not a likely cause of the issue you described.  Are you using Mathematica 10.  If not, replace `ReIm[sol[u]]` by `{Re[sol[u]], Im[sol[u]]}`.

Comment: Thank! You're right, I's using 9.0 and your suggestion makes it work!